# vertical-align:middle on text not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align `<div>` text vertically in the middle. Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oxusmkvh/1/) which I tried. But it’s not working for me.

```css
.cart_channels_main {
  float: left;
  height: 285px;
  margin: 0 18px 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.cbheading {
  background: #000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #c7a375;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif !important;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <div class="cart_channels_main">
    <div class="cbheading"><b>vertical align middle</b>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And some time i have text in 2 line, so if i use padding of margin or line height it will not work for 2 line text. like in this example [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/oxusmkvh/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.cbheading {
    background: #000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #c7a375;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
     font-family: "Roboto Condensed",sans-serif !important;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height: 30px;//added
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/oxusmkvh/3/)

For you

```
.cbheading {
    background: #000;
    color: #c7a375;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 30px;
    display: table;
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
}
.cbheading b {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: please check question again, i just updated my question. it will not work for 2 line text

Comment: yes its working in fiddle, but not working for me in my site. here is the [link](http://test.coachfxlive.com/shop)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.
Copy this code with your css.

```
  .cart_channels_main {
    float: left;
    height:auto;
    margin: 0 15px 15px 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;    
    vertical-align:middle;
}


.cbheading {
    background: #000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #c7a375;
    height: auto;    
     font-family: "Roboto Condensed",sans-serif !important;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height: 30px;

}
```

Comment: please check question again, i just updated my question. it will not work for 2 line text

Comment: Don't check the url which i give ,Please copy the css code and implement it.

Comment: not working for me when i put it in my site. see [LINK](http://test.coachfxlive.com/shop)

Answer (score 1):

You can add `line height`

Add this..

**CSS**

```
.cart_channels_main {
  float: left;
  height: 285px;
  margin: 0 18px 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

And you can do like this also..
Instead of above you can add `padding-top` so that text is vertically aligned..

```
.cbheading {
    background: #000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #c7a375;
    height: 30px;
    Padding-top:10px;
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed",sans-serif !important;

}
```

Comment: please check question again, i just updated my question. it will not work for 2 line text

Comment: @himanshuarchirayan if you  increase the height  than i think it will work

Comment: yes but if i increase height then single line text will looks odd.

Answer (score 1):

Add `height:auto` instead of `height:30px;`

Try this

```
.cbheading {
    background: #000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #c7a375;
    height:auto;  //changed this
    padding: 5px;
     font-family: "Roboto Condensed",sans-serif !important;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height: 30px;

}
```

**[Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/oxusmkvh/7/)**

Comment: thanks but i want height to be fixed. because i have many div there and if i make height auto then it looks weird.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply display property.

```
.cbheading{
  display: table;
  width:100%;
}

.cbheading b{
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align : middle;
}
```

Comment: yes its working in fiddle but when i apply it in my site then its gonna weird, see this [link](http://test.coachfxlive.com/shop)

Answer (score 1):

You can add hidden element for correct align:

```
.cbheading:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```